# How can I find the common elements in a list of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 3, 6, 4, 5, 9]
c = [5, 4, 7, 9]
d = [1, 7, 5, 6, 9, 4]
e = [4, 3, 5, 7, 1]
f = [...]
.
.
(n = [n,n,n])
```

For 1 out of many cases, we have 5 variables from **a** to **e** and we would like to get the intersection element out of these 5 arrays, without having to write nested for..loop for each case.

Please suggest the ideal solution to this problem.

Comment: What have you already tried? Show us your code. Cos this sounds like a homework/test question.

Comment: StackOverflow is not for code suggestions, it's for helping you fix code that you are trying to get to work but can't. If you post what you have tried,  and we help you understand what's not working, you will learn a lot more.

Comment: @Andy I'm just good at asking questions and explaining various terminologies and concepts, which is none related to homework or test as mentioned.

Comment: @Vicheanak, that's fine. But if you haven't provided any code that you've already attempted, then your question looks exactly like something a teacher would pose to a student, and then it comes across you as trying to get SO to do your homework for you. I hope you can see that.

Comment: @Andy Man, I've tried, like nested 5 for..loop. That would be funny if I posted my code here. Alright then, I can see your point now. Thanks for the answer too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First find the common elements between first and the second arrays and then find the common elements between the previous set of common elements and the third array and so on.

```
var listOfArrays = [a, b, c, d, e, ...];
var commons = listOfArrays.slice(1).reduce(function(result, currentArray) {
    return currentArray.filter(function(currentItem) {
        return result.indexOf(currentItem) !== -1;
    });
}, listOfArrays[0]);
```

Here,

```
currentArray.filter(function(currentItem) {...});
```

is the function responsible for finding the common elements between two arrays, `result` and `currentArray`.

We use `Array.prototype.reduce` where the value returned by the function passed to it will be fed back to the same function, in the next iteration. So, we keep on feeding the common elements from the previous iteration to the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the non-Mr.Fancy-Pants version :)

```
function findIntersection() {

    // turns the list of arguments into an array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    // concatenate all the arrays
    var all = args.reduce(function (a, b) { return a.concat(b); });

    // use the temporary object to store the number of times a
    // number appears
    for (var i = 0, obj = {}, l = all.length; i < l; i++) {
        var key = all[i];
        if (!obj[key]) obj[key] = 0;
        obj[key]++;
    }

    // return those numbers that have a value matching the number
    // of arguments passed into the function
    return Object.keys(obj).filter(function (el) {
        return obj[el] === args.length;
    }).map(Number);
}

findIntersection(a,b,c,d,e); // [ "4", "5" ]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j9bewttq/)